# C# working with drawn polygons

Tags: c#, drawing, editing, polygons

I have two questions about polygons.

1. Im drawing polygons to picturebox. The picturebox has slidebar. If i move with slidebar up or down, then polygons which are currently not vissible are deleted. Im working with C# just 2 months so Im still newbie. How to fix that problem?
2. It is possible to click on polygons and with mouse move with them or change their size?

Best Regards

```
for (int i = 0; i < final_rng.Count; i++) 
{
    listPoint.Clear(); 
    for (int j = 0; j < final_rng[i].body.Count; j++)
    { 
       listPoint.Add(new Point(final_rng[i].body[j].X, final_rng[i].body[j].Y)); 
     }
//for (int j = 0; j < final_rng[i].body.Count; j++)
    grafika.FillPolygon(Brushes.Turquoise, listPoint.ToArray()); }
//for (int i = 0; i < final_rng.Count; i++)
```

Comment: It depends on how your storing your drawing primitives, if you just draw them to screen then you will lose them as soon as they are outside the bounds

Comment: Ok, so i have this code 

<code>for (int i = 0; i < final_rng.Count; i++)
      {
        listPoint.Clear();
        for (int j = 0; j < final_rng[i].body.Count; j++)
        {
          listPoint.Add(new Point(final_rng[i].body[j].X, final_rng[i].body[j].Y));
        }//for (int j = 0; j < final_rng[i].body.Count; j++)</code>
        grafika.FillPolygon(Brushes.Turquoise, listPoint.ToArray());
      }//for (int i = 0; i < final_rng.Count; i++)

which add polygon to picturebox. Can you give me another hint how to store polygons? 

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you draw directly on the `PictureBox`, the drawn polygons will be lost when the control is repainted (e.g. when you resize the window). A better way is to draw on a `Bitmap` and add then show it in the `PictureBox`. An example:

```
// A new bitmap with the same size as the PictureBox
var bitmap = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);

//Get the graphics objectm which we can use to draw
var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);

//Draw stuff
graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, new Rectangle(0, 0, 500, 500));

//Show the bitmap with graphics image in the PictureBox
pictureBox1.Image = bitmap;
```